# How to pass multiple "userIds" in secret.json in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Our app has a C# backend and we launch its server in Visual Studio.

Recently a `secret.json` file was added in which each developer added its authentication email:

```
{
  "Init": {
    "userId": "myemail@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

What I need is to login with several accounts at once, I do it from two different browsers.

When trying to login with a different email than the one mentioned in the `secret.json` file then it doesn't work.

Is it possible to enter an array of emails as `"userIds"`? Should I change anything else too apart than in the `secret.json` ?

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60234030/how-to-add-values-through-user-secrets-to-an-array-of-objects-in-c-sharp) that probably talks about this same issue but it seems that's for an old version of the environment or the editor (I have no idea since I never write any C# code myself or use Visual Studio for other than to launch the backend server for our app) .

Comment: It is quite unclear what `userId` has to do with the login functionality and how this connection is set up. You definitely can set and array in config but the question is how it is handled in your app.

Comment: @GuruStron Seems **userId** isn't a build-in parameter. I have no clue what waits for it and where that should be validated

Comment: No, it is not. You have access to the codebase, not us, so it's up to you to discover.